# VBA Outlook // BroseForFolder: How to access to all folders (Explorer.exe)

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

i need your help. 
What code do I have to add in order to get access to all folders (like the standard explorer window). Especially to the linked folders. 
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Here is my Code:

```
Option Explicit
 Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant

  Dim ShellApp As Object

 Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
      BrowseForFolder(0, "Bitte den Ordner auswählen:", &H1000, OpenAt)

 'Set BrowseDir = ShellApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Bitte Ordner auswählen", &H4000, OpenAt)

 On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
     On Error GoTo 0

 Set ShellApp = Nothing
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
        Case Is = ":"
            If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
       Case Is = "\"
            If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Else
            GoTo Invalid
    End Select
   Exit Function

Invalid:
 BrowseForFolder = False


End Function

Public Sub speichern()

    Dim oMail As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath, strFolderpath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim enviro As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

    strFolderpath = BrowseForFolder
    sPath = strFolderpath & "\"

    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            Set oMail = objItem
            sName = oMail.Subject
            ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
              vbUseSystem) & " " & "-" & " " & UCase(Split(Trim(Split(objItem.SenderEmailAddress, "@")(0)), ".")(1)) & " " & "-" & " " & sName & ".msg"
            Debug.Print sPath & sName
            sName = InputBox( _
            prompt:="Dateiname. Bei Fertigstellung OK klicken.", _
            Default:=sName)
            oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
         End If
    Next
End Sub

   Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: A linked folder can not be accessed as a normal folder. In Windows a linked folder is a file.

Answer (score 0):

Hummm, I just answered a question like this less than 1 minute ago.  I think you want to list all files in all folders and all sub-folders. Check out this link.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Download the file; that's the way to go.

i) User wants to get the list of All files inside a folder
Copy and Paste the below Code and this will list down the list of all the files inside the folder. This will list down all the files only in the specified folder. If there are other files which are there in some other Sub-folders.
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String)  

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\"  

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject  
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder  
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File  

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject  
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)  

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured  

    r = 14  
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files  
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13  
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name  
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path  
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size  
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type  
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified  
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"  

        r = r + 1   ' next row number  
    Next FileItem  

    Set FileItem = Nothing  
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing  
    Set FSO = Nothing  
End Sub
```

ii) User wants to get the list of all files inside a folder as well as Sub-folders
Copy and Paste the below Code and this will list down the list of all the files inside the folder as well as sub-folders. If there are other files which are there in some other Sub-folders then it will list down all files from each and Every Folders and Sub-folders.
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)  

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No  

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject  
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder  
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File  
'Dim r As Long  
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject  
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)  

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured  

    r = 14  
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files  
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13  
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name  
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path  
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size  
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type  
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified  
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"  

        r = r + 1   ' next row number  
    Next FileItem  

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.  

    If Subfolders = True Then  
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders  
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True  
        Next SubFolder  
    End If  

    Set FileItem = Nothing  
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing  
    Set FSO = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you pls help me to integrate the code into mine? :/